# How to open or link to a preference pane from within an Firefox SDK add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'd like to open my add-on's preference pane, however it seems not possible. (I can't find any documentation about it on MDN)

The thing is, my add-on needs some user credentials and I want these to be accessible on this preference pane. It feels logical to "redirect" the user to this preference pane upon first using my add-on, that way he or she can fill in said credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question just now here: https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=16276&sid=51109b951d7ee2da09f233374ea69667

I feel bad you didnt get a reply to this for so long. :(

next time use tag "firefox-addon"

Comment: The link is dead but there is another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593454/has-ff-addon-sdk-an-api-to-open-settings-page/22601737#22601737) on SO.