# Has FF Addon SDK an API to open settings page?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I use [simple-prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs) module to configure addon settings. How can I ***programmatically*** open addon's settings page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do this in a [test add-on here](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/test/addons/simple-prefs/lib/main.js#L48)

There is more code there than you need though, so the shorter version is:

```
const self = require('sdk/self');
const tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

tabs.open({
  url: 'about:addons',
  onReady: function(tab) {
    tab.attach({
      contentScriptWhen: 'end',
      contentScript: 'AddonManager.getAddonByID("' + self.id + '", function(aAddon) {\n' +
                       'unsafeWindow.gViewController.commands.cmd_showItemDetails.doCommand(aAddon, true);\n' +
                     '});\n'
    });
  }
});
```

In words, this opens the `about:addons` page in a new tab, waits for it to load, then opens the details page for your add-on.